# Subtraction of inventory from Demand in BigQuery everday and adding new inventory

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Here's how my data looks like:

| date | sku | inventory_added | demand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22nd Nov 2021 | XYZ | 70 | 18 |
| 23rd Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 18 |
| 24th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 50 |
| 25th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 15 |
| 26th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 80 | 30 |
| 27th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 20 |
| 28th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 15 |
| 29th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 20 |
| 30th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 10 |
| 1st Dec 2021 | XYZ | 100 | 40 |
| 2nd Dec 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 10 |

I want to create a new column named `solution` using BigQuery SQL where in the 1st row, i.e. 22nd Nov 2021, I want formula as - `inventory_added - demand`.
This will give me 1st row's value for `solution` will be 52.

Now what I am not able to do is from 2nd row:
So, next now, will be `52 (remaining inventory from previous day) + 0 (inventory_added on 23rd Nov 2021) - 18 (demand on 23 Nov 2021)`. This is equal to 34.

Similarly going to next row, i.e. 24th November:
value in `solution` will be `34 + 0 - 50 = -16`. Now since it is negative, it should be put as 0.

I tried this - `MAX(solutions, 0)`.

The result will look like this:

| date | sku | inventory_added | demand | solution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22nd Nov 2021 | XYZ | 70 | 18 | 52 |
| 23rd Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 18 | 34 |
| 24th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 50 | 0 |
| 25th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 15 | 0 |
| 26th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 80 | 30 | 50 |
| 27th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 20 | 30 |
| 28th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 15 | 15 |
| 29th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 20 | 0 |
| 30th Nov 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 1st Dec 2021 | XYZ | 100 | 40 | 60 |
| 2nd Dec 2021 | XYZ | 0 | 10 | 50 |

I am not sure if this can be accomplished by BigQuery, but all suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without the condition "it is negative, it should be put as 0" you may use window (in BigQuery terms - analytic) variant of [SUM() function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#sum):

```sql
SELECT *, 
       SUM(inventory_added - demand) OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY date) AS solution
FROM source_table
```

With this condition the output become iterative, and you must use recursive CTE (if available in BigQuery) or iterative stored procedure.

---

> I see that recursive CTE is not available in BigQuery ... Can you provide a pseudo code may as a starting point for stored procedures? – Shantanu Jain

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procname()
BEGIN
    CREATE temptable;
    OPEN CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM datatable ORDER BY date;
    SET @solution = 0;
    FETCH CURSOR INTO @date, @sku, @inventory_added, @demand;
    LOOP    ​
       ​ SET @solution = GREATEST(@solution + @inventory_added - @demand, 0);
       ​ INSERT INTO temptable VALUES (@date, @sku, @inventory_added, @demand, @solution);
        FETCH CURSOR INTO @date, @sku, @inventory_added, @demand;
    UNTIL NO_ROWS_IN_CURSOR END LOOP;
    SELECT * FROM temptable;
    DROP temptable;
END
```

Comment: Thanks @Akina, however, I see that recursive CTE is not available in BigQuery and I don't have much experience with 'iterative stored procedures'. Can you provide a pseudo code may as a starting point for stored procedures? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @ShantanuJain Pseudocode (similar to MySQL syntax) added.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Akina, I will try now. :)

Answer (score 0):

AS an option - consider use of recently introduced [FOR...IN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#for-in) Loop

```
declare result int64;
declare prev_sku string;

create temp table results as (select *, 0 as solution from your_table where false);

set (result, prev_sku) = (0, '');
for record in (select *, parse_date('%d %B %Y', regexp_replace(date, r'(\d*)(\w*)( \w{3} \d{4})', r'\1 \3')) dt from your_table order by sku, dt) do
  if record.sku != prev_sku then set result = 0; end if;
  set result = result + record.inventory_added - record.demand;
  if result < 0 then set result = 0; end if;
  insert into results values(record.date, record.sku, record.inventory_added, record.demand, result);
  set prev_sku = record.sku;  
end for;
select * from results 
order by sku, parse_date('%d %B %Y', regexp_replace(date, r'(\d*)(\w*)( \w{3} \d{4})', r'\1 \3'));
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: While delivering expected result - obviously this is going to be extremely slow (as any cursor based solution) - so while applicable for learning - I don't think appropriate for real production use

Comment: have you tried? did it work for you?